# Customer community around a product

Tags: web, product-management

I am looking for creating a community site for our customers who use our product. I would like to have Q&A alike forum, features suggestions, blog and articles, users management etc.

Anyone can recommend such product?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Productific (https://productific.com). The SaaS tool addresses the need to manage a backlog of feature ideas and match them with user needs (feedback, voting, ranking).

Productific uses a four step approach:

1. Describe an idea
2. Publish it to your users
3. Collect feedback
4. Decide what to build based on the feedback data

It's currently free to use. Feature suggestions are on the roadmap.

Comment: You are one of the creators?

Comment: Yes. Appreciate feedback and suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Super-sized image at https://productific.com/doc/How-to-prioritize-your-Product-Backlog-SLbg